# How to force Chrome to open an "open file dialog" when downloading a file vía ASP.NET codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, httpresponse

I have a page that sends a binari file, pdf, word or excel to web browser. In firefox, and IE both opens a dialog asking what do you whant to do with this file, "open" or "save"

[image]

but **Chrome** directly save it to your computer.

Is it possible to **make Chrome ask you what do you want to do with this file**, placing some metadata into web response before sending the file to browser?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It isn't possible to force Chrome to prompt the save dialog. The user has to change that behavior on chrome's configuration **(advanced settings)**.

[image]

Comment: Where would that setting be?

Comment: But asking user to tick this check box is not practical right, So is there is any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send some headers so the browser knows how to handle the thing you are streaming like:

```
Response.ContentType 
Content-Disposition, application,and 
filename=" + FileName
```

which will force a download. Also refer this link for more information :

http://www.devtoolshed.com/aspnet-download-file-web-browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be helpful

```
System.String filePath = "c:\\tempFile.pdf"
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
System.Web.HttpResponse response = context.Response;
response.Clear();
response.ClearHeaders();
response.ClearContent();
response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
response.AppendHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.pdf", outputFileName));
response.TransmitFile(filePath);
response.Flush(); // this make stream and without it open chrome save dialog
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // send headers and c# server-side code still continue

System.IO.File.Delete(filePath); // clean cache here if you need

response.End();
```